# sink.hdfs writer adds garbage in my text file

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I have successfully configured flume to transfer text files from a local folder to hdfs. My problem is when this file is transfered into hdfs, some unwanted text "hdfs.write.Longwriter + binary characters" are prefixed in my text file. 
Here is my flume.conf

```
agent.sources = flumedump
agent.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sinks = flumeHDFS

agent.sources.flumedump.type = spooldir
agent.sources.flumedump.spoolDir = /opt/test/flume/flumedump/
agent.sources.flumedump.channels = memoryChannel

# Each sink's type must be defined
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://bigdata.ibm.com:9000/user/vin
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.fileType = DataStream

#Format to be written
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text

agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.maxOpenFiles = 10
# rollover file based on maximum size of 10 MB
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 10485760

# never rollover based on the number of events
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 0

# rollover file based on max time of 1 mi
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 60


#Specify the channel the sink should use
agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.channel = memoryChannel

# Each channel's type is defined.
agent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory

# Other config values specific to each type of channel(sink or source)
# can be defined as well
# In this case, it specifies the capacity of the memory channel
agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 100
```

My source text file is very simple containing text :
Hi My name is Hadoop and this is file one.

The sink file I get in hdfs looks like this : 
SEQ !org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable org.apache.hadoop.io.Text������5����>I <4  H�ǥ�+Hi My name is Hadoop and this is file one.

Please let me know what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out. 
I had to fix this line

`agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.fileType = DataStream`

and change it to

`agent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream`

this fixed the issue.